# How can I install openrave package for Fuerte?

Tags: ros, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the openrave ROS package for Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04, but I can't find it (nothing looking like ros-fuerte-openrave... in the available packages in the repositories).

The wiki page http://ros.org/wiki/openrave says "Cannot load information on name: openrave, distro: fuerte" so I don't know where should I get the source code from to install the package from source.

Does anyone know how could I install this package?

Edit: I've found this question http://answers.ros.org/question/32866/installing-openrave-package/ where the code of the openrave_planning (that happens to contain the package I need) is checked out from:

```
svn co https://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jsk-ros-pkg/trunk/openrave_planning
```

I assume this is the right repo, but still the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openrave_planning) doesn't point to the right data, and no package for this stack exists in the ROS fuerte ubuntu repositories.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51803/how-can-i-install-openrave-package-for-fuerte?/) by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's the right place, I used a couple of packages from there with Fuerte last year.

People may write great ROS packages for their own research, but not have enough time to create a Ubuntu package or maintain external documentation like ROS wiki.

This guide will help you install it:
http://sourceforge.net/p/comps/wiki/Installation/

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on 2013-01-24**:
Thanks for the link. I finally installed openrave standalone, as I found out that it was only being used as a library by our package (we don't use any ROS node that the openrave ROS package may contain).